# Prove the Markovness from independent variables

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, markov-process, independence, stochastic-filtering

Let $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ be two independent random variables. Consider the following equations:

\begin{align}
\mathbf{x} &= f(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{w}),\\
\mathbf{z} &= g(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{v}).
\end{align}

Then, how to prove $p(x|y,z) = p(x|y)$? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the appropriate keywords are the d-separation and the Bayes ball algorithm [(relevant link)](https://www.cse.ust.hk/bnbook/pdf/l03.h.pdf). It is an efficient algorithm to verify the conditional independence.

Comment: Thanks a lot! [+1] Could you provide a detailed proof?

Comment: Just draw the directed graphical model and check the d-separation between x and z.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments :-)

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that $\sigma(y,z) = \sigma(y, g(y,v)) = \sigma(y,v)$ (assuming that both $g$ and $f$ are measurable). For $h$ a test function, we then have
$$\mathbb{E}[h(x)|y,z] = \mathbb{E}[h(f) (y,w) | y,z] = \mathbb{E}[h(f) (y,w) |y, v] = \mathbb{E} [h(f) (y,w) | y].$$
I assumed that you can prove something like 
$$ \mathbb{E}[h(f)(y,w) \mathbf{1}_A(y) \mathbf{1}_B(v)] = \mathbb{E}[h(f)(y,w) \mathbf{1}_A(y)] $$ for any sets $A$ and $B$ which will give you the last equality of my previous equations. This should be ok if you have a clue about the joint law of $y$ and $v$ (or of $z$ and $y$).

Comment: Thanks a lot! [+1] I have two questions: 1) What does $\sigma$ refer to? 2) Why do we use the expectation rather than the pdf?

Comment: $\sigma(X)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the random variable $X$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra. The real definition of conditional probabilities only works with $\sigma$-algebras. When we write a probability conditionnaly on the variable $X$, what it really means is conditionally on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$ (intuitively that means conditionally on all the information given by $X$).

Comment: Pdf is just a particular case of expectation, where you take for instance $h(x) = \mathbf{1}_{x \leq y}$ for some $y$ for instance. Usually the computations are clearer with expectations because of the relation with integrals (and the fact that we can use techniques from integration/measure theory).

Comment: I am still confused. $\sigma$-algebra should be on a sample space.

Comment: I thought pdf is a Radon–Nikodym derivative. But yes, it can be defined by integrations.

Comment: You have a sample space, otherwise you don't have random variables (which are functions from your sample spaces to $\mathbb{R}$. For the pdf, note that $\mathbb{E}[h(x) |y,z] = \int h(x) p(x|y,z) dx $ so you can work with expectations. I think case 3 on slide 8 of the link posted below should help you.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments.